# Envolver con el texto alrededor de la imagen mediante flex

Tags: css, flexbox

alguien sabe como lograr este efecto que se logra mediante float con flexbox:

[image: Efecto con float]

Ya que mediante flex no se envuelve la imagen y el espacio inferior de la imagen queda sin ser ocupado:

```
CSS

body { 
    font-family: Arial; 
}
.container {
    max-width: 500px;
    display: flex;
}
img {
    align-self: baseline;
}
p { 
    margin: 0 0 0 10px; 
}
HTML

<div class="container">
    <img src="img.png">
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Aenean est lectus, venenatis sit amet nisl sed, molestie 
    interdum elit. Proin maximus fermentum rhoncus. 
    Vestibulum blandit ligula ligula. Mauris volutpat cursus 
    enim eu iaculis. Duis condimentum ante sed dolor lacinia 
    imperdiet. Phasellus felis orci, dictum sed elit sed, 
    lobortis congue sem. Etiam at tortor diam. 
    </p>
</div>
```

[image: Recrear efecto con flex]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo realizas con flexbox este tomara cada elemento como un hijo, razón por la cual tienes ese resultado. Quitale `display: flex`, agrega `float:left` a la imagen y conseguiras tu cometido.

**Ej:**

```css
body { 
    font-family: Arial; 
}
.container {
    max-width: 500px;
}
img {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="https://png.pngtree.com/element_our/png/20181206/users-vector-icon-png_260862.jpg" >
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Aenean est lectus, venenatis sit amet nisl sed, molestie 
    interdum elit. Proin maximus fermentum rhoncus. 
    Vestibulum blandit ligula ligula. Mauris volutpat cursus 
    enim eu iaculis. Duis condimentum ante sed dolor lacinia 
    imperdiet. Phasellus felis orci, dictum sed elit sed, 
    lobortis congue sem. Etiam at tortor diam. 
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Aenean est lectus, venenatis sit amet nisl sed, molestie 
    interdum elit. Proin maximus fermentum rhoncus. 
    Vestibulum blandit ligula ligula. Mauris volutpat cursus 
    enim eu iaculis. Duis condimentum ante sed dolor lacinia 
    imperdiet. Phasellus felis orci, dictum sed elit sed, 
    lobortis congue sem. Etiam at tortor diam. 
</div>
```